# accessing id element of parent page from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

How can I access id element from iframe to parent page? I have tried to use this method but still not work.

**Parent.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Parent</title>
    </head>
    <body> 
    <button id="click" onclick="alert('Hello');">click</button>
        <iframe id="iframe1" src="iframe.html">
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

**iframe.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Parent</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var money = 20000;

    $("#nominal").on("change keyup", function() {
        var input = $(this);

        // remove possible existing message
        if( input.next().is("form") )
            input.next().remove();

        // show message
        if( input.val() > money )
            window.parent.$('#click').trigger('click');
    });
});
</script>
    </head>
    <body> 
    <input type="text" id="nominal">
    </body>
</html>
```

Whether there is something wrong with the script I created? Please help me to improve this code. Thanks in advance.

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

Comment: are you getting any error in console?

Comment: are you trying to access id - iframe1 , because i see iframe1 id in both htmls

Comment: @RinoRaj `TypeError: window.parent.$ is not a function`

Comment: @NagaSaiA i'm trying accessing id="click" in parent.html from iframe

Comment: I you solved the issue, write an answer an mark it as solved. Pls do not write the solution inside your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to use jQuery on the parent window although it is not defined in that context. It is only defined in the child document.

Instead change your child iframe script to call jQuery on the parent window's element. Here's an example:

**Parent Document**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parent</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="click" onclick="alert('Hello')">click</button>
    <iframe id="iframe1" src="iframe.html">
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Child (Iframe) Document**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parent</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <input type="text" id="nominal">

    <script>
      $(function() {
          var money = 20000;

          $("#nominal").on("change keyup", function() {
              var input = $(this);

              // remove possible existing message
              if (input.next().is("form")) {
                  input.next().remove();
              }

              // show message
              if (input.val() > money) {
                $(window.parent.document.getElementById('click')).trigger('click');
              }
          });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/ks8oFmQyxHYFt0h8eBbF?p=preview

**Alternatively**

You could also drop jQuery altogether for something as simple as triggering a click:

```
// replace this
$(window.parent.document.getElementById('click')).trigger('click');

// with this
window.parent.document.getElementById('click').click();
```

A note on safety: this is a fairly brittle approach in that you *must* know that a specific element exists in the parent document with that specific id attribute. It would be better to at least have some checks for existence before calling `click` on a node that may not be present.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option:

1.Create onclick function-check in parent.html
2.Use it in iframe.html using parent.check()

Parent.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Parent</title>
    </head>



    <body> 
        <script>
      function getId(){

       alert('Hello')
      }

    </script>
    <button id="click" onclick="getId()">click</button>
        <iframe id="iframe1" src="iframe.html">
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

iframe.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Parent</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var money = 20000;

    $("#nominal").on("change keyup", function() {
        var input = $(this);

        // remove possible existing message
        if( input.next().is("form") )
            input.next().remove();

        // show message
        if( input.val() > money ){
        parent.getId();
            window.parent.$('#click').trigger('click');
    }
    });
});
</script>
    </head>
    <body> 
    <input type="text" id="nominal">
    </body>
</html>
```

plunker-https://plnkr.co/edit/OBHTxA8adzoFEvD4eowA?p=preview